The ideal sheaf $\mathscr{J}_{S}$ isomorphic to the sheaf $\mathcal{O}\left(L_{S}^{*}\right)$ of holomorphic sections of the dual bundle $L_{S}^{*}$
This is a problem from Lee's new book on complex manifolds.

Proposition 5.16. Suppose $M$ is a complex manifold, $S \subseteq M$ is a closed complex hypersurface, $L_{S} \rightarrow M$ is the holomorphic line bundle associated with $S$, and $E \rightarrow M$ is any holomorphic vector bundle.

The ideal sheaf $\mathscr{J}_{S}$ is isomorphic to the sheaf $\mathcal{O}\left(L_{S}^{*}\right)$ of holomorphic sections of the dual bundle $L_{S}^{*}$.
More generally, the sheaf $\mathscr{F}_{S}(E)$ of holomorphic sections of $E$ vanishing on $S$ is isomorphic to $\mathscr{I}_{S} \otimes_{\mathcal{O}} \mathcal{O}(E) \cong \mathcal{O}\left(L_{S}^{*} \otimes E\right)$.
The sheaf $\mathscr{S}_{S}^{2}(E)$ of holomorphic sections of $E$ that vanish to second order on $S$ is isomorphic to $\mathcal{O}\left(L_{S}^{*} \otimes L_{S}^{*} \otimes E\right)$.


For 1. I'm thinking that this can be proven by considering the local defining system $\{(U_\alpha,f_\alpha)\}$ for $Y$ in which $U_\alpha \cap Y = f^{-1}_\alpha(\{0\})$ and then proving that the map $$\Phi : \mathscr{I}_S(U_\alpha) = \mathcal{O}_M(U_\alpha)\cdot f_\alpha \to \mathcal{O}(U_\alpha,L^*_S)$$ for which $\Phi(h \cdot f_\alpha) = h e^*_\alpha$ is an isomorphism? Here $e^*_\alpha$ should be a local frame over $U_\alpha$ for the line bundle $L^*_S$. Is this a correct approach here?
